# datetime.strptime - does not accept abbreviated german months running on Linux(Ubuntu) Is there a work around?

Tags: python, linux, date, datetime, ubuntu

I need to convert dates represented as strings into datetime objects in python.
Dates look like this:

"04. Mrz. 2021"

I have already set the correct locale:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import locale

# Let's set a german locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
print(locale.getlocale())
auction_date = datetime.strptime("03. Mrz. 2021", "%d. %b. %Y")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tony/Documents/DEV/Whisky_Data/sandbox.py", line 8, in <module>
    auction_date = datetime.strptime("03. Mrz. 2021", "%d. %b. %Y")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '03. Mrz. 2021' does not match format '%d. %b. %Y'
```

I have done some research and it seems like the "Mrz" is causing the issue.
It works well with "Mär" and initially I thought the dates I get are just not correctly formatted. However according to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monat) DIN ISO 8601 specified that "Mär" should be abbreviated "Mrz" in Germany to avoid issues with coding due to the umlaut "ä".

So the dates I get are technically correctly formatted, however it seems like this has not been considered in either the locale "de_DE.utf8" or in the implementation of datetime.strptime

UPDATE:
As @MrFuppers pointed out, the code does run just fine using Windows 10 Python 3.6. It seems this problem is specific to Linux/Ubuntu.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: your code works just fine when I tested, Win10 / Python 3.8, don't have a Unix system around right now, but it works also fine in cygwin / Python 3.6.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I am using Ubuntu. Knowing that it works just fine using Windows, I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: yup, can reproduce on Linux/Ubuntu. `datetime.now().strftime("%b")` returns `'Mär'`

Comment: as for me it can be problem with system settings, not `datetime.strptime` but I don't know tools to check if system has the same problem with `Mrz`

Comment: afaik, strptime / strftime falls back to platform-dependent implementations / C libraries. So I believe that technically, this is not a Python issue - but it sounds like you need a (nasty) workaround *in* Python to get a platform-independent solution ;-)

Comment: Does your system have German locale data for (g)libc? `locale -a` (on the command-line) shows all installed locales. Does `date -d 2021-03-01 +%b` command print and German month name?